# Model object has no attribute save while reducing size of CoreML?

Tags: python, coreml

i am reducing the size of CoreML. I make this CoreML with Python Turicate but i am getting a error `Model object has no attribute save`. I have `Python 2.7` and `pip install coremltools==2.0b1` before execute python file. Here's my code -

```
import coremltools
from coremltools.models.neural_network.quantization_utils import *
model = coremltools.models.MLModel('/Users/Desktop/MLClassifier/animals.mlmodel')
lin_quant_model = quantize_weights(model, 16, "linear")
lin_quant_model.save('/Users/Desktop/animals2.mlmodel')
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you're not on macOS 10.14 or later (Mojave), in which case you don't get an MLModel but the model specification when you call `quantize_weights()` (according to the docs). No idea why, but that's what it says.

Comment: i am also returning this warning WARNING! Unable to return a quantized MLModel instance since OS != macOS 10.14 or later
Returning quantized model specification instead

Comment: Thnx for ur answer

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this problem, running model quantization on Ubuntu (Python 3.8, coremltools==4.1).

I don't know why exactly this error occurs (maybe it should be run on macOS), but as you are getting specs, you can get and save model as follows:

```
    model_fp16_specs = quantization_utils.quantize_weights(model_fp32, nbits=16)
    model_fp16 = ct.models.MLModel(model_fp16_specs)

    model_fp16.save("model_quantized.mlmodel")
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked :) I ended up with the same issue when running on Ubuntu 20.04. When running the quantization call on the coreML model object I received the specs as output and a warning in the console - WARNING - Unable to return a quantized MLModel instance since OS is not macOS 10.14 or later. Returning a quantized model specification instead.